# I have a PHP script that repeats the same set of task 30 times. How do I break it into pieces that will run one after another to avoid a timeout?

Tags: php, ajax, cron

I have a PHP script that is set to fetch 30 RSS feeds when I run it.

It grabs the first feed, does moderate to heavy amount of processing on to individual articles and adds them to a mysql database. Then it moves on to the next feed. The script echoes a message everytime it adds an article to the database.

As you can tell the process is very lengthy and I'm afraid of the script timing out. I'd rather not increase the timeout limit and instead make the code more scalable. Also when the script is running I don't see any visual progress up until the very end. This was somewhat fixed with ob_flush() but it still doesn't output the confirmations after every article, or every feed.

There must be a better way to run this process. I have very little idea on how I should go about it, so I can't think of very many good search queries to learn this myself.

My best idea at the moment is to breakup the update process into 30 different files for 30 feeds. Then using AJAX (which I'm not too familiar with) to load one after another, automatically. Would this solve the timeout problem?

Is there a better way of going about it?

I'd very much appreciate any and all help pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Have you tried invoking it independent of the web server?

Comment: Don't run it via a webserver then. Run it as a standard CLI script via chron, where the execution time limits don't apply

Comment: @MarcB and Ignacio I'm on a shared hosting account. I have cron job that runs it every 10 minutes. What I add so many more feeds that it takes longer than 10 minutes to run?

Comment: Ah. shared hosting... then you're stuck and will have to make it a much shorter job. e.g. process one rss feed, then reschedule itself to run the next feed as a new separate/job.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a few other things that depend on fixed time intervals between updates :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that you want to break the task up so that each iteration runs 3 RSS feeds. You could place a .txt file within the same directory as your script and read/write to it at the beginning and end of each iteration.

For example, initialize the .txt file to 0. When the first iteration finishes, update the .txt to 3, and so on until you finish the cycle, at which you can have the code reset the file to 0.

Then you can call the script by cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options available to solve this problem.

Solution 1:
Say there are in total n steps to be followed. Do them one by one managed by querystring  parameter and echo a meta tag to redirect to step 2 in a second or so e.g.

```
switch($_GET["stepNo"])
case 1: performStep1(); break;
...
```

Redirection

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://example.com/?stepNo=5">
```

Solution 2:
As you said AJAX would be a good choice, even then you break it into multiple steps (even function would work), and call individual step one by one proceeding when you get a response. Here also your code will be like above.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, I did not think of meta refresh :)